# Else statement is not recognized in C# what am I missing?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement

In C# the program is supposed to count how many valid and invalid values were entered by comparing them to the array and then give a total of the correct and incorrect inputs, but when I enter numbers that are outside of the bounds of the if statement the code from the if statement still runs. I've gone back and reviewed videos and the textbook and I cannot see where my if else statement is lacking.

```
        int[] values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, };
        int count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value between 0 and 10");

        foreach (int v in values)
        {
            
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (values[v] >= 0 || values[v] <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");
                
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
                
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} correct values", count);
        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} incorrect values", count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great time to learn about [debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022), you can set the breakpoint and hovering on the statements will tell you what is the result of each condition.

Comment: Why are you using the same `count` variable for correct and incorrect? If you get out a calculator an add 1 for each incorrect value, and likewise add 1 for each correct value, you get one number at the end. How do you hope to decompose this one number into the separate numbers for correct and incorrect values? You need separate variables for that in the same way you might need two calculators.

Answer (score 3):

(values[v] >= 0 || values[v] <= 10) will always return true, all numbers are either less than 10 or greater than zero. Presumably you want an and (&&) operator to grab values between 0 and 10 inclusive

Also, foreach iterates through the values of an array, not the index, so you don't need to reference values[v], you can just reference v directly (although in your case values[v]==v). Calling values[v] in a foreach runs a huge risk of indexOutOfBounds exceptions. If you want to iterate through the index a straight for loop is more appropriate:

```
for(int i = 0; i< values.Length; i++)
     var myVal = values[i];
```

Final Edit, you aren't actually checking the user's input

```
var input = Console.ReadLine(); 
//you never bothered capturing the user's input with a variable
decimal myNum;
if (decimal.TryParse(input, out myNum)) //did the user give a number?
{
    //use myNum instead of values[v]
}
else
{ 
    //process bad input
}
```

There's a bunch of stuff you can do to make things cleaner, (like removing your array altogether and using for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++) instead, for example), but good code doesn't happen on day 1 (my first few projects make me wanna throw up now), you got this friend.

Comment: There are a number of logical issues beyond just this comparison. For instance, the count operator does essentially nothing because it is the variable for both cases, the input value isn't compared to the looped values, and then as you mentioned, the evaluation isn't inclusive.

Comment: I reread the question after posting the answer, my monkey brain tried to answer the question with no care for the intent behind it, I must be a programmer hahaha, hopefully OP will be able to work through his problem more now at least

Answer (score -1):

You have a foreach loop, you do not need to use

```
if (values[v] >= 0 || values[v] <= 10)
```

instead, use

```
if(v >= 0 || v <= 10)
```

plus your `if` statement will always return true because the value you have in your array of `int` is greater than or equals to 0 or less than or equals to 10.

Try to change the array from

```
int[] values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, };
```

to

```
int[] values = { -5, 1, 2, 3, 11, 5, 6, 13, 8, 9, 15, };
```

and you should have 4 incorrect count, provided you separate the correct count and incorrect count instead of adding them together using the `count`.
Separate them into `validCount` and `invalidCount`